# Android: How I get amplitude from mediaplayer?

Tags: android

I need to get amplitude from mediaplayer.

I try to use AudioManager, mAudioManager.getStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC ); 
but is not my need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution.
Can use Visualizer
API Level 9.